# Currency calculation program - Nested Lists and Table

Tags: python

I have a small program that has a list of currencies and two functions.

First function funcOne(currency) takes all exchange rates and in range(10, 101, 10) calculates for every number.

Second function funcTwo(currency, t) displays all the information in formatted table.

```
def funcOne(currency):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(10, 101, 10):
        aud = i * currency[0][1]
        usd = i * currency[1][1]
        eur = i * currency[2][1]
        gbp = i * currency[3][1]
        curList = [i, aud, usd, eur, gbp]
        matrix.append(curList) 
    return(matrix)

def funcTwo(currency, t):
    print("$NZ \t{} \t{} \t{} \t{} \t".format(currency[0][0], currency[1][0], currency[2][0], currrency[3][0]))
    for i in t:
        print("%0.2f" % i[0], "\t%0.2f" % i[1], "\t%0.2f" % i[2], "\t%0.2f" % i[3], "\t%0.2f" % i[4], "\t")

currency = [['Euro', 0.2],['GBP', 0.3],['AUD', 0.4],['USD', 0.5]]
t = funcOne(currency)
funcTwo(currency, t)
```

Result expected to looks something like this:

```
$NZ     Euro    GBP     AUD     USD     
10.00   2.00    3.00    4.00    5.00    
20.00   4.00    6.00    8.00    10.00   
30.00   6.00    9.00    12.00   15.00   
40.00   8.00    12.00   16.00   20.00   
50.00   10.00   15.00   20.00   25.00   
60.00   12.00   18.00   24.00   30.00   
70.00   14.00   21.00   28.00   35.00   
80.00   16.00   24.00   32.00   40.00   
90.00   18.00   27.00   36.00   45.00   
100.00  20.00   30.00   40.00   50.00
```

The issue is that if there is extra currency added, the program cannot display it.

For example:

```
currency = [['Euro', 0.2],['GBP', 0.3],['AUD', 0.4],['USD', 0.5],['RUB', 0.12]]
```

What changes can I make to make display table with any number of currencies?

I'm sorry, if it's not very clear, please ask for clarification. I run out of any ideas how to make things work. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
def funcOne(currency):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(10, 101, 10):
        curList =[]
        for j in range(len(currency)):
            curList.append(currency[j][1] * i)
        matrix.append(curList) 
    return(matrix)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. 
What can I do for the second function that displaying it in table?

Comment: You can use `print('\t'.join(listName))` to print a tab separated list

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
def funcTwo(currency):
    names = [c[0] for c in currency]
    print("$NZ\t" + ' \t'.join(names))
    for i in range(10, 101, 10):
        print(i, end='\t')
        curList = [str(i * c[1]) for c in currency]
        print(" \t".join(curList))

currency = [['Euro', 0.2],['GBP', 0.3],['AUD', 0.4],['USD', 0.5],['RUB', 0.12]]
funcTwo(currency)

print()
currency = [['Euro', 0.2],['GBP', 0.3],['AUD', 0.4],['USD', 0.5]]
funcTwo(currency)
```

Output:

```
$NZ Euro    GBP     AUD     USD     RUB
10  2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0     1.2
20  4.0     6.0     8.0     10.0    2.4
30  6.0     9.0     12.0    15.0    3.5999999999999996
40  8.0     12.0    16.0    20.0    4.8
50  10.0    15.0    20.0    25.0    6.0
60  12.0    18.0    24.0    30.0    7.199999999999999
70  14.0    21.0    28.0    35.0    8.4
80  16.0    24.0    32.0    40.0    9.6
90  18.0    27.0    36.0    45.0    10.799999999999999
100 20.0    30.0    40.0    50.0    12.0

$NZ Euro    GBP     AUD     USD
10  2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0
20  4.0     6.0     8.0     10.0
30  6.0     9.0     12.0    15.0
40  8.0     12.0    16.0    20.0
50  10.0    15.0    20.0    25.0
60  12.0    18.0    24.0    30.0
70  14.0    21.0    28.0    35.0
80  16.0    24.0    32.0    40.0
90  18.0    27.0    36.0    45.0
100 20.0    30.0    40.0    50.0
```

Comment: I don't think its working correctly with function call. 

currency = [['Euro', 0.2],['GBP', 0.3],['AUD', 0.4],['USD', 0.5]]
t = funcOne(currency)
funcTwo(currency, t)

Comment: You don't need `funcOne` anymore if you use my solution

Comment: also `funcTwo` only need 1 argument